# Saving the state of my ListView for screen orientation

Tags: android, listview, bundle

I went through many posts for screen orientation.
But my scenario is little bit different. My ListView have custom row layout. With ImageView bitmap being loaded from internet using AsyncTask. What I want is to, is it possible to save the ArrayAdapter of my ListView or the whole ListView so that its state is preserved upon orientation screen change.

Please suggests some posts or if some codes are posted it will be very useful.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Contents entry = contentList.get(position);
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater infltr = null;
            if (row == null) {
                infltr = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlight_contents_layout,
                        parent, false);
        }

            ImageView imgViewImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgView_Image);
            if (imgViewImage.getTag() == null) {
                new DownloadImage(imgViewImage, entry).execute(); //Async Task to download Image
            }

        }
        return row;
    }
```

and in onCreate i have a function call to populate the list the function call is :

```
init(){
listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); //vairable declared at top of my class;
contentlist = new ArrayList<Contents>(); //Variable Declared at top of class;

//... Populated the contenlist... in here
//..
//..
adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout._contents_layout, contentList,
                thumb_image_bytes);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can preserve state of your `ListView` by using [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) method. This method is executed before activity is destroyed during orientation change and it can return any object you want, for example your list adapter. Leter, in `onCreate()` method that object can be restored by calling `getLastNonConfigurationInstance(`);

So create field in your activity, for example `mAdapter`. That field will hold reference to your list adapter. Override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` like this:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mAdapter;
}
```

And restore list adapter in `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    Object obj = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    if(null != obj){//if there is saved adapter - restore it
        mAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)obj;
    } else { //if not - create new one
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    }
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**Edit:**

This doesn't look good for me:

```
ImageView imgViewImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgView_Image);
      if (imgViewImage.getTag() == null) {
           new DownloadImage(imgViewImage, entry).execute(); //Async Task to download Image
}
```

Please, check if `imgViewImage.getTag()` ever returns false. I think You shouldn't execute `AsyncTask` in `getView()` because it will be executed while you are scrolling list so you could get list items with no imager(I think).

Comment: not working... I have some images in my row which are downloaded from the internet. When I change the orientation it gets downloaded again. How can I handle this? But the texts which are downloaded from the internet for the textView in my list remains in its place. How can I handle this?

Comment: I have implemented the following code:

if (customClass.getImageSourceBytes() == null) {
     new DownloadImageTask(imgView, customClass).execute();
} else if (customClass.getImageSourceBytes().length > 0) {    imgView.setImageBitmap(convertBitmap(customClass.getImageSourceBytes()));}

It works, on orientation change the else part is fired, without the need of downloading the image again. But ImageView is not showing the image. I don't know why? Do I need to reinitialize again?

Comment: Could you past code of onCreate() and your list adapter (especially getView() method)

Comment: I was thinking a way round. Why not save the byte[] of my images in persistent storage. So when ever I rotate my screen I will be loaded from my persistent storage. 

If you have some other idea please share.

Comment: Yes, You could save images in some persistent storage but I'am still curious why my solution did't work for you. I think you should move AsyncTask outside of your adapter. Try to download all imager before setting adapter, pass array of images to adapter and then saving adapter state should work because getView is executed everytime list item is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you store the downloaded data in variables, and upon change of orientation, reload the elements with the stored data. [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) will help you catch the screen orientation change event.

Comment: I was thinking a way round. Why not save the byte[] of my images in persistent storage. So when ever I rotate my screen I will be loaded from my persistent storage. If you have some other idea please share.

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking. But you can set the orientation so that it is fixed to a certain value. I had a problem where I had a list view change on orientation so I fixed the orientation so that it would only produce the output in portrait mode.

I added this tag inside my activity tags as an option

```
<activity android:name="preferences.Preferences" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>.
```

I hope this is the answer that you were looking for. This will preserve the state. If this does not answer your question. I will endeavour to help you further.